# How to prevent users from directly accessing my html website?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, login-page

I've been messing around and trying to create an HTML website with a login page. Problem is, you can bypass the login page by typing (domain)/page.html, so I tried using this javascript script.

```
<script>
var x = document.referrer;    

if (x == "(domain)") {
    console.log(x);
} else {
    window.location.href = "/";
};
</script>
```

After adding that to my code, I ran into another problem. I go through the login page and hit submit. It redirects me to page.html like it should, but then it instantly redirects me back to the login page. Can someone help with this?

Comment: What's `"(domain)"`?

Comment: If I’m an attacker that wants to view these pages, why wouldn’t I just disable JavaScript and access the URL anyway…? You need to study up on how to perform authorization on your server side - purely client-side JavaScript is not a good choice for this, as it can be manipulated very, *very* easily.

Comment: You need some kind of authentication system, but for a very lo-fi approach, you could set a cookie when someone does log in correctly. On page.html you could sniff for the cookie before displaying the contents. Of course, anyone could turn off javascript. Another method would be to use htpasswd...

Answer (score 0):

On client side one can easily mess with your code.You should study how to perform authentication on the server-side.

If in case you are using PHP as backend then in login.php file you should do it as follows

```
//after login verified
//You have to learn how to make a verification token
setcookie("remember",$ver_token,time()+45345345 ,"/",true,);
header("Location: http://www. (domain)/page.php/");

// some additional menipulation if you want
```

And in the page.php file you will get the cookie else redirect to the login.php file

```
// On the top of the login.php file 
if (isset($_COOKIE['remember'])) {
// Check in the database and do other stuff
}
else{
header("Location: http://www. (domain)/login.php/");
}
```

My suggestion is first learn some about backend programming and then try to do login because a hacker or attacker may easily view the page.html file because no verification on the server side. Client side can be manipulated very very easily.